# take item from list and keep track of the modified list

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, clojurescript

Say there's a list called `xs`. This list needs to be filtered by a predicate and a random element needs to be taken from the result:

```
(rand-nth (filter pred? xs))
```

This would return one item of the list. What should be done if, additionally the original list (minus the extracted item) needs to be retained?

Are those two steps necessary or is there a quicker way to do so?

```
(let [item (rand-nth (filter pred? xs))
      new-xs (remove (partial = item) xs)]
   ...)
```

Comment: Do you actually have performance problems? Otherwise you're guilty of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: thanks for reminding me. maybe you are right. As noted below, this approach would remove duplicate items. However, my data doesn't contain those (so it could be a set) - I'll stick to my lines.

Comment: Do you pull just one element from each list? You retaining the remnant suggests otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution will fail for duplicated elements in your input `xs` as all of duplicates will be removed when they are randomly selected.

I would rather choose random index by myself and use it directly:

```
(defn remove-nth [xs n]
  (when (seq xs)
    (if (vector? xs)
      (concat
        (subvec xs 0 n)
        (subvec xs (inc n) (count xs)))
      (concat 
        (take n xs)
        (drop (inc n) xs)))))

(defn remove-random [xs]
  (if (seq xs)
    (let [index (rand-int (count xs))
          item (nth xs index)
          remaining (remove-nth xs index)]
      [item remaining])))
```

Comment: This looks like you're reinventing the wheel. Btw there's already a [rand-nth](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rand-nth) function.

Comment: Yes, I know but OP wants to also remove the element from the randomly selected index and `rand-nth` returns a bare value without information about its position in the original sequence.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Still looks like too much code and OP solution is shorter and thus better (from a functional pov) at first look.

Comment: I also mentioned it in my answer: for duplicated items in the input collection they will all be removed if a single one will be randomly selected. My solution removes an item exactly from the selected index, not all identical items.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do this without keeping the binding for `item` like this:

```
user> (defn split-rnd [pred coll]
        (let [[l [it & r]] (split-with (complement
                                        #{(rand-nth (filter pred coll))})
                                       coll)]
          [it (concat l r)]))
#'user/split-rnd

user> (split-rnd pos? [-1 2 -3 4 -5 6 -7])
[4 (-1 2 -3 -5 6 -7)]

user> (split-rnd pos? [-1 2 -3 4 -5 6 -7])
[6 (-1 2 -3 4 -5 -7)]

user> (split-rnd pos? [-1 2 -3 4 -5 6 -7])
[2 (-1 -3 4 -5 6 -7)]
```